# Writing a function that performs the same job as set_symmetric_difference

Tags: c++

Hello all and sorry for taking your time!
 I am doing online exercises and I have been given the task to write a template function that does the same job as `set_symmetric_difference`. The function takes five parameters `p1, p2, p3, p4 p5`. `p1 and p2` are the boundaries of the first block, `p3 and p4` the boundaries of the second block, `p5` points at the beginning of the destination block.

Note: There are three different parameter types because the p1 and p2 can be pointers while p3 and p4 can be iterators.

The function should find the symmetric difference of two sets but with certain conditions:

1. **No duplicates allowed** (i.e. if there's already an element of the value `x` in the set of symmetric difference, another one with the same value is not to be copied).
2. **All elements must be in the same order of the original two blocks**
3. **The elements of the first block are to be copied before the elements of the second block**.
4. **The function returns an iterator/pointer which points not at the beginning of the destination block, but at the point *after the last element in the block*.**

I've had no luck so far in fixing this. My solution works for some instances but for others it does not work. I have absolutely no idea on how to follow rules 1,2 and 3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

template <typename type1, typename type2, typename type3> 
type3 symmetric(type1 p1, type1 p2, type2 p3, type2 p4, type3 p5) {
   sort(p1,p2);
   sort(p3,p4);

   while(true) {
      if(p1 == p2) return copy(p3,p4,p5); 
      if(p3==p4) return copy(p1,p2,p5);
      if(*p1 < *p3) {
         *p5=*p1;
         p5++;
         p1++;
      }

      else if(*p3 < *p1) {
         *p5 = *p3;
         p3++;
         p5++;

      }
      else {
         p1++;
         p3++;
      }
   }
   return p5;
}

int main ()
{
   int block1[] = { 5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7, 4 };
   int block2[] = { 2, 9, 0, 6, 0, 4, 8, 3, 2, 5 };
   int destination[10];
   auto p = symmetric(block1, block1+10, block2, block2+10, destination);
   auto destination_begin = destination;
   while(destination_begin < p) cout << *destination_begin++;
   return 0;
}
```

For the example I mentioned the output should be `7 1 9 0 8` but my program prints `0 0 1 4 7 7 8 9`. I have no idea how to fix it. Sorry for my ignorance and I'd be delighted if someone came to the rescue! Thanks a million times!

Comment: You could start with an implementation of [set_symettric_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) and then adjust it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your output is expected to be sorted. Hence it needs to be `0 1 7 8 9`, not `7 1 9 0 8`.

The key piece of logic that is missing in your code is that you are not skipping duplicate entries when iterating over the input lists.

Here's an updated version of your posted code that works for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

template <typename type> 
void print(type p1, type p2)
{
   while(p1 != p2) cout << *p1++ << " ";
   cout << endl;
}

template <typename type> 
type skip_duplicates(type p)
{
   while ( *p == *(p+1) ) ++p;
   return ++p;
}

template <typename type1, typename type2, typename type3> 
type3 symmetric(type1 p1, type1 p2, type2 p3, type2 p4, type3 p5) {
   sort(p1,p2);
   sort(p3,p4);

   print(p1, p2);
   print(p3, p4);

   while(true) {
      if(p1 == p2) return copy(p3,p4,p5); 
      if(p3 == p4) return copy(p1,p2,p5);
      if(*p1 < *p3) {
         *p5=*p1;
         p5++;
         p1 = skip_duplicates(p1);
      }

      else if(*p3 < *p1) {
         *p5 = *p3;
         p3 = skip_duplicates(p3);
         p5++;

      }
      else {
         p1 = skip_duplicates(p1);
         p3 = skip_duplicates(p3);
      }
   }
   return p5;
}

int main ()
{
   int block1[] = { 5, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 3, 2, 7, 4 };
   int block2[] = { 2, 9, 0, 6, 0, 4, 8, 3, 2, 5 };
   int destination[10];
   auto p = symmetric(block1, block1+10, block2, block2+10, destination);
   print(destination, p);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you maybe know how I could modify this program in order not to sort the values, so I'd get the output I mentioned? Thanks again!

Comment: @ff998 `set_symmetric_difference` requires sorted sequences to work correctly.  Even if you came up with a way to do this without sorting, the algorithmic complexity would probably be worse than simply sorting the sequences first.